# Apache docket container not starting using docker-compose up

Tags: docker, apache2.4, hippocms

I'm working on a use case to create a Docker container for an apache server for a CMS application.

Below is the folder structure for the docket container.

```
apache-rproxy-docker (folder)
  -docker-compose.yml
  - httpd (folder)
     - Dockerfile
     - httpd.conf
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  apache:
    build: httpd/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - my_network
    restart: always

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 80

ServerName localhost:80
ServerAdmin admin@localhost

ErrorLog logs/error.log
LogLevel error

###
# Note that the following LoadModule lines only represent the minimum 'Web-Developer' Suite configuration.
#
# Also note that some of the following LoadModule lines, which are commented out, are still loaded under…
# confSuite-extra*.conf
# confextra*.conf
# …configuration files -- for modular reasons.
# 
# For example:
# mod_deflate is loaded under confSuite-extramod_deflate_logio.conf and NOT under httpd.conf
# status_module is loaded under confextrahttpd-info.conf and NOT under httpd.conf
#
# Check last part of httpd.conf for the Apache base and 'Web-Developer' *.conf files that are included.
###

#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
#LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
#LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so


#CMS
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName cms.dev.local

  ProxyPreserveHost  On
  #INCLUDE THE EXTRA PROXYPASS RULE FOR /site HERE
  ProxyPass /site/ http://localhost:8080/site/
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/cms/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/cms/
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /cms /
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a couple of issues which are holding me back,

1. While I'm able to build the container with no issue, but when trying to up the container using "**docker-compose up**", the container starts and terminates instantaneously without any errors.
2. I don't see the port mapping for the container, which is odd.

[image]

Below is the output on executing **docker inspect container_id**.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1d40fcc6c4c1383213386bbdfbed0434a4b86ebbfc79e18d450691d57f190c86",
        "Created": "2018-11-19T21:32:39.9551494Z",
        "Path": "httpd-foreground",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 1,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-11-19T21:32:40.7494723Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2018-11-19T21:32:40.8537987Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:31f9d98b9ee458dbf1befb5e07c87c6ef959dcc2ef690fe523fd887b12f9dbf9",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1d40fcc6c4c1383213386bbdfbed0434a4b86ebbfc79e18d450691d57f190c86/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1d40fcc6c4c1383213386bbdfbed0434a4b86ebbfc79e18d450691d57f190c86/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1d40fcc6c4c1383213386bbdfbed0434a4b86ebbfc79e18d450691d57f190c86/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/1d40fcc6c4c1383213386bbdfbed0434a4b86ebbfc79e18d450691d57f190c86/1d40fcc6c4c1383213386bbdfbed0434a4b86ebbfc79e18d450691d57f190c86-json.log",
        "Name": "/apache-rproxy-docker_apache2_1_71f4a0b7076b",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "apache-rproxy-docker_spa_network",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4040cf05d15260b3de19e00df9ef8f05305e581372162d3d280603d1d741148a-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/84adfc08eb41b4f6ede14df10775b291c8195ade8b5d6351892e7c0f0606bc92/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5e42bbf563f3fbc5829685509b13f1d5536886a68ee5bd913bd4910dc9737478/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/48ccff5d0d55c955e8e3e49b62c01865826dbfd01bd25206c411ae69f08bda4e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fa24d9a31cc583d8a9583e659d94a5fc507328449cfb066bbcd2d3da2d26d2bd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33fec7b43c22926678461a9b352c8cafdc7ede8303cb3d90722e30c0f20731c2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c91cbd2e7230cc22d9ac1e170ca724c478c4b708e0edc433dd035f4ff36d9957/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4040cf05d15260b3de19e00df9ef8f05305e581372162d3d280603d1d741148a/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4040cf05d15260b3de19e00df9ef8f05305e581372162d3d280603d1d741148a/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4040cf05d15260b3de19e00df9ef8f05305e581372162d3d280603d1d741148a/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "1d40fcc6c4c1",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/apache2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "HTTPD_PREFIX=/usr/local/apache2",
                "HTTPD_VERSION=2.4.37",
                "HTTPD_SHA256=3498dc5c6772fac2eb7307dc7963122ffe243b5e806e0be4fb51974ff759d726",
                "HTTPD_PATCHES=",
                "APACHE_DIST_URLS=https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?action=download&filename= \thttps://www-us.apache.org/dist/ \thttps://www.apache.org/dist/ \thttps://archive.apache.org/dist/"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "httpd-foreground"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "apache-rproxy-docker_apache2",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/local/apache2",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "df3b431078c66f67a39bb27012c1d8237e21a65cac4c1a69a30db3f25f27d7d3",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "apache-rproxy-docker",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "apache2",
                "com.docker.compose.slug": "71f4a0b7076baa5b84ae33dda673173f29bb709e4904493b2b80847fa98f8e4",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.1"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "d27a9df7fe5a9e75f5c3444f95565389cccde58f3791237c266430b1cced8d18",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/d27a9df7fe5a",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "apache-rproxy-docker_spa_network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "apache2",
                        "1d40fcc6c4c1"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "c2a24a5495f429efcff44ca247af058e29503a8e5659355cab7d0f3fe135f3b8",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I'm working on the docker for the first time. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: We need the logs from the Apache container. The most relevant part will be the end (where I assume it's exiting for some reason). It might be easier if you remove `restart: always` at least temporarily. You can get the logs with `docker-compose logs`, or from the terminal itself it it's not in daemon mode.

Comment: @mkasberg -  One running "docker-compose logs". I just got this statement -  
Attaching to apache-rproxy-docker_apache_1_71f4a0b7076b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was able to reproduce your issue using the files you provided. It's weird that you're not getting more info in the logs. But here's how I debugged it:

1. The fact that the status is `restarting` is bad - it means your container isn't staying up. I removed the `restart: always` line, but got the same result.
2. Let's narrow down the problem some more. I built your Dockerfile and ran it by running the following commands in the `httpd` directory: `docker build -t apache-rproxy:latest . && docker run --rm -p 80:80 apache-rproxy:latest`. Unfortunately, I got the same error with no additional logs.
3. Let's debug some more. Try the same command with the official httpd image: `docker run --rm -p 80:80 httpd:2.4`. Notice that this time, httpd starts and begins logging, and the container remains alive.

Now, the only difference between the `httpd:2.4` image and the `apache-rproxy:latest` image is your config file. So you something in your `httpd.conf` is preventing apache from starting (or even logging anything). Work out what the problem is there and I think you'll have a working setup.

Comment: Thank you !! :-) I did try something similar, using the steps laid out in https://www.matthewsetter.com/basic-docker-compose-debugging. Even I came to the conclusion with the issue being the httpd.conf file.